# Counting opening parenthesis in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, parentheses

I am trying to count number of symbols with the string.punctuation module in python in a dataframe column but I can not find a way to have the opening parenthesis to be counted as python thinks does not consider it a string apparently.

I am working on linux + Jupyter notebook and python 3.8.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['password'] = data
df['sign'] = 0
for i in string.punctuation:
    print(i)
    print(type(i))
    df['sign'] += df['password'].str.count(i)
    
df['sign'].iloc[:100]
```

This gives me:

```
!
<class 'str'>
"
<class 'str'>
#
<class 'str'>
$
<class 'str'>
%
<class 'str'>
&
<class 'str'>
'
<class 'str'>
(
<class 'str'>
```

and afterwards the exception:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    834             p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
    835             if not source.match(")"):
--> 836                 raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",
    837                                    source.tell() - start)
    838             if group is not None:

error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['hel\\l\'o', 'hellO()world']})
```

Parentheses are part of the regex syntax so you need to escape them:

```py
df['text'].str.count('\(')
```

To cover all of `string.punctuation` you can use:

```py
df['text'].str.count(f'[{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]')
```

Comment: Enclosing the pattern in `[]` is a great idea +1

Comment: Why did you enclose it with brackets [{ ?

Comment: To use variables in f-strings you wrap them in curly braces e.g. `print(f"2+2 equals {2+2}!")`

Comment: As for the square brackets `count("abc")` will count occurrences of the three letters together while `count("[abc]")` will count the total number any of these three letters appear in your string. So the first will return 2 for "abcabc" and 0 for "cbacba" while the second will return 6 in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked also if anyone gets here:

```
count = lambda l1,l2: sum([1 for x in l1 if x in l2])
df['punctuation'] = df['password'].apply(lambda s: count(s, string.punctuation))
```

Comment: it's much much slower as you loop over each of your strings `len(string.punctuation)` number of times